# Using a variable in Python selenium XPATH

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a variable as follows:

```
client_Id = driver.execute_script("return getCurrentClientId()")
```

I am trying to replace the last value in the XPATH (after `clientid=2227885`) i.e.`2227885` with the variable client_Id. So:

```
prog_note = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@href='/admin/client/cp_progressnotes.jsp?ESOLclientid=2227885']")))
```

Should have the number component, in this case, `2227885` replaced with `client_Id` variable.

How could I go about this? I tried the following to no success

```
prog_note = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@href, 'cp_progressnotes', "+client_Id + "')]")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xppath = "//a[@href='/admin/client/cp_progressnotes.jsp?ESOLclientid={}']".format(client_Id )

prog_note = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
```

use format